# PHP MySQL 5 minimize query

Tags: php, mysql, minify

> ```
> $query = mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `username` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = 'admin' LIMIT 1");
> if (mysql_num_rows($query))
> {
>     $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
>     $userid = $row['id'];
> }
> ```

I need to get userid so fast .
How I can minify this code? I very often use related queries.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You query is almost nothing can do of minimizing except you don't need to get the `username` field which is already know in your where clause. And `mysql_fectch_assoc()` return false if there is no record, so you do not need to use `mysql_num_rows()`.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = 'admin' LIMIT 1");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
if ($row) {
     $userid = $row['id'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is `id` then only include `id` in the SELECT. If `username` is unique, you don't need `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = 'admin'
```

If `id` is your primary key, then ensure that you have an index on `username`.

If you're not using the row count, then skip the call to `mysql_num_rows()`. Also, returning only numeric indexes with `mysql_fetch_row()` might help some:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = 'admin'");
if ($query)
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($query);
    if($row) {
        $userid = $row[0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to ask mysql to explain your query :

```
EXPLAIN SELECT `id`, `username` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = 'admin' LIMIT 1
```

And follow the response to optimize your request

---

Use a PrimaryKey to SELECT the row or set username as INDEX

Answer (score 0):

My sugesstion is to wrap it in a function for this (getting the id).
I subscribe to what others have said about mysql_num_rows and the username in the query.

```
function get_uid($username);
{
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `username`='{$username}' LIMIT 1");
    return ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) ? $row['id'] : NULL;
}
```

and use as

```
$userid = get_uid('admin');
```

if you get input from somewhere, escape the username.